# Two tables one contain records and second conatain location i want to show first table record with out join

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am working on it Two tables contain records; one is the admin table, which contains all detail, and the second location of shops first I want to check latitude and longitude and get  the result from shop_location it works fine, and after that, I want to check the status of a shop which is on and show the result

Here is my MYSQL QUERY, which works fine

```
SELECT DISTINCT s_number,radious, ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( 
   latitude ) ) * COS( RADIANS( "33.5967558" ) ) * COS( RADIANS( 
    "73.3869814" ) - RADIANS( longitude ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( latitude 
  ) ) * SIN( RADIANS("33.5967558" ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM 
   Shop_Location HAVING distance <= radius/1000 ORDER BY distance 
     ASC
```

HERE IS MY SECOND Query

```
SELECT * from Admins WHERE shopstatus='ON'
```

Phonenumber in both tables is the same but not unique  I want to get the result from shop_location Query and after that check status of a shop (ON) show Result.

I want to solve it with Query.

Comment: 'with out join' ? Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HERE IS THE RIGHT ANSWER

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
Admins.email,Admins.address,Admins.adminname,
Admins.diliveryfee,Admins.endingtime,Admins.minorder
,Admins.name,Admins.password,Admins.shopimage,
Admins.shopmessage,Admins.phonenumber,
 Admins.shopname,Admins.shopstatus FROM (
 SELECT Admins.email,Admins.address,Admins.adminname,Admins.diliveryfee,Admins.endingtime,Admins.minorder,Admins.name,Admins.password,Admins.shopimage,Admins.shopmessage,Admins.phonenumber,Admins.shopname,Admins.shopstatus,Shop_Location.radious AS shopLocationRadius, ( 6371 * ACOS( COS( 
  RADIANS( latitude ) ) * COS( RADIANS( "33.5967558" ) ) * 
  COS( RADIANS( "73.3869814" ) - RADIANS( longitude ) ) + 
    SIN( RADIANS( latitude ) ) * SIN( 
     RADIANS("33.5967558" ) 
      ) ) ) AS distance FROM Shop_Location INNER JOIN 
    Admins ON 
    (Admins.phonenumber = Shop_Location.s_number) WHERE 
    Admins.shopstatus='ON'  HAVING distance <= radious/1000 
   ORDER BY distance ASC)
     AS Admins
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that both tables are linked with "s_number" (shop number) , you may try the following SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT Shop_Location.s_number,radious, ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( 
   latitude ) ) * COS( RADIANS( "33.5967558" ) ) * COS( RADIANS( 
    "73.3869814" ) - RADIANS( longitude ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( latitude 
  ) ) * SIN( RADIANS("33.5967558" ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM 
   Shop_Location, admins where
Shop_Location.s_number=admins.s_number and admins.shopstatus='ON'
 HAVING distance <= radius/1000 ORDER BY distance 
     ASC
```

Comment: Looks like a join to me

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Shop_location.s_number,
    Shop_location.radious,
    (
        3959 * ACOS(
            COS(RADIANS(latitude)) * COS(RADIANS("33.5967558")) * COS(
                RADIANS("73.3869814") - RADIANS(Shop_location.longitude)
            ) + SIN(
                RADIANS(Shop_location.latitude)
            ) * SIN(RADIANS("33.5967558"))
        )
    ) AS DISTANCE,
    Admins.shopstatus
FROM
    Shop_Location
LEFT JOIN
    Admins
ON
    Admins.s_number = Shop_location.s_number
HAVING
    DISTANCE <= radius / 1000
ORDER BY
    DISTANCE ASC
```